# LINQ Contains condition based on multiple search criteria in Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: sqlite, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a string parameter that's split up into multiple search filters depending on the outcome of a `Split(',')` operation. I want to select all entities where the title field **contains** any of the search  filters

I'd expect the following LINQ to work

```
    string[] filters = param.Split(',');

    var query = await
        (from t in this.Context.Persons
         from f in filters.Where(f => t.Title.Contains(f))
         select t).ToListAsync();
```

However exequting the query I'm getting the following error:

```
Processing of the LINQ expression 't => __filters_0
    .Where(f => t.Title.Contains(f))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You have to use a predicate builder to build a query with `or` predicates. Side note: the query looks a bit odd, you multiply `Persons` by the number of matching keywords.

Comment: Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61559911/861716.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold - your mentioned link proved useful. LinqKit would work for me, however I ended up implementing a generic WhereAny extension method on IQueryable<T> as described here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a generic LikeAny extension method on IQueryable as described here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10834

Comment: That's a lot of custom code for something a predicate builder will do generically.

Comment: I have one extension method LikeAny, 20 lines of code, and it’s generic. I.e can filter on any property and it’s a one liner to call. I prefer this over bringing in an external NuGet package and let and then having to force the client code  to loop to build the OR predicate